# Extract a subset of key-value pairs from dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, associative-array

I have a big dictionary object that has several key value pairs (about 16), but I am only interested in 3 of them. What is the best way (shortest/efficient/most elegant) to subset such dictionary?

The best I know is:

```
bigdict = {'a':1,'b':2,....,'z':26} 
subdict = {'l':bigdict['l'], 'm':bigdict['m'], 'n':bigdict['n']}
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way than this.

Answer (score 608, accepted):

You could try:

```
dict((k, bigdict[k]) for k in ('l', 'm', 'n'))
```

... or in Python versions 2.7 or later:

```
{k: bigdict[k] for k in ('l', 'm', 'n')}
```

I'm assuming that you know the keys are going to be in the dictionary. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352546/best-way-to-extract-subset-of-key-value-pairs-from-python-dictionary-object/5352649#5352649) by [Håvard S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94237/havard-s) if you don't.

Alternatively, as [timbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127660/timbo) points out in the comments, if you want a key that's missing in `bigdict` to map to `None`,  you can do:

```
{k: bigdict.get(k, None) for k in ('l', 'm', 'n')}
```

If you're using Python 3, and you *only* want keys in the new dict that actually exist in the original one, you can use the fact to view objects implement some set operations:

```
{k: bigdict[k] for k in bigdict.keys() & {'l', 'm', 'n'}}
```

Comment: Will fail if `bigdict` does not contain `k`

Comment: @Håvard S: I think from the OPs post, we can assume that all given given elements are in `bigdict`.

Comment: "or in Python 3" or "or in Python >= 2.7"?

Comment: `{k: bigdict.get(k,None) for k in ('l', 'm', 'n')}` will deal with the situation where a specified key is missing in the source dictionary by setting key in the new dict to None

Comment: Thanks, @timbo - I've added that to the answer too, hope that's OK

Comment: @MarkLongair Depending on the use case {k: bigdict[k] for k in ('l','m','n') if k in bigdict} might be better, as it only stores the keys that actually have values.

Comment: Upvoting this _and_ the linked answer by @HåvardS, which is exactly what I was looking for. I love it when devs cite code properly.

Comment: I hope my edit is not too presumtuous. @BrifordWylie's version might be better if you want to avoid an essentially undocumented feature.

Comment: @hop Thanks for the addition - I made a small change just to make it clear that it only works on Python 3.

Comment: How can I check if `['l','m','n']` is a substring of `k`?

Comment: `bigdict.keys() & {'l', 'm', 'n'}`  ==> `bigdict.viewkeys() & {'l', 'm', 'n'}`   for Python2.7

Comment: `{ x : bigdict[x] for x in (1, 2, 3) if x in bigdict.keys() }` to avoid `KeyError` and the `None` values.

Comment: The last solution is nice because you can just replace the '&' with a `-` to get an "all keys except" operation. Unfortunately that results in a dictionary with differently ordered keys (even in python 3.7 and 3.8)

Comment: What if my `dict` is too big?

Comment: dict.get(k), will return `None` by default if k is not found, no need to explicitly set that default as a param

Answer (score 153):

A bit shorter, at least:

```
wanted_keys = ['l', 'm', 'n'] # The keys you want
dict((k, bigdict[k]) for k in wanted_keys if k in bigdict)
```

Comment: +1 for alternate behavior of excluding a key if it is not in bigdict as opposed to setting it to None.

Comment: Alternatively: `dict((k,bigdict.get(k,defaultVal) for k in wanted_keys)` if you must have all keys.

Comment: This answer is saved by a "t".

Comment: Also a bit shorter variant (syntax) of your solution is when using `{}`, i.e. `{k: bigdict[k] for k in wanted_keys if k in bigdict}`

Answer (score 37):

A bit of speed comparison for all mentioned methods:

UPDATED on 2020.07.13 (thx to @user3780389):
ONLY for keys from bigdict.

```
 IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Python 2.7.18 (default, Aug  8 2019, 00:00:00) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)] on linux2
import numpy.random as nprnd
  ...: keys = nprnd.randint(100000, size=10000)
  ...: bigdict = dict([(_, nprnd.rand()) for _ in range(100000)])
  ...: 
  ...: %timeit {key:bigdict[key] for key in keys}
  ...: %timeit dict((key, bigdict[key]) for key in keys)
  ...: %timeit dict(map(lambda k: (k, bigdict[k]), keys))
  ...: %timeit {key:bigdict[key] for key in set(keys) & set(bigdict.keys())}
  ...: %timeit dict(filter(lambda i:i[0] in keys, bigdict.items()))
  ...: %timeit {key:value for key, value in bigdict.items() if key in keys}
100 loops, best of 3: 2.36 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.87 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.65 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 7.14 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 577 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 563 ms per loop
```

As it was expected: dictionary comprehensions are the best option.

Comment: The first 3 operations are doing a different thing to the last two, and will result in an error if `key` doesn't exist in `bigdict`.

Comment: nice. maybe worth adding `{key:bigdict[key] for key in bigdict.keys() & keys}` from the [accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5352630/3780389) which accomplishes the filter while actually being faster (on my machine) than the first method you list which doesn't filter.  In fact, `{key:bigdict[key] for key in set(keys) & set(bigdict.keys())} ` seems to be even faster for these very large sets of keys ...

Comment: @telchert you are missing, that in the giving speed comparison bigdict.keys() & keys are not sets. And with explicit conversion to sets accepted solution is not so fast.

Comment: List comprehension is not really the best, the "ugly" solution proposed in the question is even faster.

Comment: @kriss What is "ugly" solution? With hard-coded keys? Of cause solution with hard-coded something will be faster, no question.

Comment: The OP asked for a more elegant/faster solution than what he proposed: build a new dictionary in place with the expected keys. Ugly may be a bit strong, but knowing how much time we are loosing because we want to use a generic list of keys for mere elegance purpose (notice that the OP list of wanted keys is known beforehand) would be interesting. Hence, OK, maybe "of course it is faster' (something I wouldn't blindly agree on, performance issues can be tricky)... but by how much ? It would be very interesting to have it in the comparison benchmark.

Comment: Can be done preparing some text python expression and compiling it to byte code at run time. `s = ', '.join(f'{key}:bigdict[{key}]' for key in keys); code = compile('{'+f'{s}'+'}', '<string>, 'eval')` `%timeit eval(code)`

Comment: For large numbers of keys it's not faster. But it could also be some artefact of test setting, because it's the only mesure where case code is using eval (which wouldn't be needed in production code).

Comment: Your message would be more straight-to-the point with a conclusion on the fastest method

Comment: This is excellent, because in my case this happened to be a crucial part of an apache beam pipeline where it would run *many* times and was time-critical!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

```
interesting_keys = ('l', 'm', 'n')
subdict = {x: bigdict[x] for x in interesting_keys if x in bigdict}
```

Comment: @loutre how else do you propose to ensure you extract all the data for the given keys?

Comment: sry I made a mistake. I was thinking you were looping on "bigdict". My bad. I delete my comment

Answer (score 18):

This answer uses a dictionary comprehension similar to the selected answer, but will not except on a missing item.

python 2 version:

```
{k:v for k, v in bigDict.iteritems() if k in ('l', 'm', 'n')}
```

python 3 version:

```
{k:v for k, v in bigDict.items() if k in ('l', 'm', 'n')}
```

Comment: ...but if the big dict is HUGE it will still be iterated over completely (this is an O(n) operation), while the inverse would just grab 3 items (each an O(1) operation).

Comment: The question is about a dictionary of only 16 keys

Answer (score 9):

An alternative approach for if you want to retain the majority of the keys while removing a few:

```py
{k: bigdict[k] for k in bigdict.keys() if k not in ['l', 'm', 'n']}
```

Comment: Even shorter: 
`{k: v for k, v in bigdict.items() if k not in ['l', 'm', 'n']}`

Answer (score 7):

Maybe:

```
subdict=dict([(x,bigdict[x]) for x in ['l', 'm', 'n']])
```

Python 3 even supports the following:

```
subdict={a:bigdict[a] for a in ['l','m','n']}
```

Note that you can check for existence in dictionary as follows:

```
subdict=dict([(x,bigdict[x]) for x in ['l', 'm', 'n'] if x in bigdict])
```

resp. for python 3

```
subdict={a:bigdict[a] for a in ['l','m','n'] if a in bigdict}
```

Comment: Fails if `a` is not in `bigdict`

Comment: the things that are said to work only in python 3, also work in 2.7

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `map` (which is a *very* useful function to get to know anyway):

`sd = dict(map(lambda k: (k, l.get(k, None)), l))`

Example:

```
large_dictionary = {'a1':123, 'a2':45, 'a3':344}
list_of_keys = ['a1', 'a3']
small_dictionary = dict(map(lambda key: (key, large_dictionary.get(key, None)), list_of_keys))
```

PS: I borrowed the `.get(key, None)` from a previous answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, this is something that has bothered me a few times, so thank you Jayesh for asking it.

The answers above seem like as good a solution as any, but if you are using this all over your code, it makes sense to wrap the functionality IMHO. Also, there are two possible use cases here: one where you care about whether all keywords are in the original dictionary. and one where you don't. It would be nice to treat both equally.

So, for my two-penneth worth, I suggest writing a sub-class of dictionary, e.g.

```
class my_dict(dict):
    def subdict(self, keywords, fragile=False):
        d = {}
        for k in keywords:
            try:
                d[k] = self[k]
            except KeyError:
                if fragile:
                    raise
        return d
```

Now you can pull out a sub-dictionary with

```
orig_dict.subdict(keywords)
```

Usage examples:

```
#
## our keywords are letters of the alphabet
keywords = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
#
## our dictionary maps letters to their index
d = my_dict([(k,i) for i,k in enumerate(keywords)])
print('Original dictionary:\n%r\n\n' % (d,))
#
## constructing a sub-dictionary with good keywords
oddkeywords = keywords[::2]
subd = d.subdict(oddkeywords)
print('Dictionary from odd numbered keys:\n%r\n\n' % (subd,))
#
## constructing a sub-dictionary with mixture of good and bad keywords
somebadkeywords = keywords[1::2] + 'A'
try:
    subd2 = d.subdict(somebadkeywords)
    print("We shouldn't see this message")
except KeyError:
    print("subd2 construction fails:")
    print("\toriginal dictionary doesn't contain some keys\n\n")
#
## Trying again with fragile set to false
try:
    subd3 = d.subdict(somebadkeywords, fragile=False)
    print('Dictionary constructed using some bad keys:\n%r\n\n' % (subd3,))
except KeyError:
    print("We shouldn't see this message")
```

If you run all the above code, you should see (something like) the following output (sorry for the formatting):

> Original dictionary:
>          {'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 4, 'd': 3, 'g': 6, 'f': 5,
>           'i': 8, 'h': 7, 'k': 10, 'j': 9, 'm': 12, 'l': 11, 'o': 14,
>           'n': 13, 'q': 16, 'p': 15, 's': 18, 'r': 17, 'u': 20,
>           't': 19, 'w': 22, 'v': 21, 'y': 24, 'x': 23, 'z': 25}
>
> Dictionary from odd numbered keys:
>          {'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'e': 4, 'g': 6, 'i': 8, 'k': 10, 'm': 12, 'o': 14, 'q': 16, 's': 18, 'u': 20, 'w': 22, 'y': 24}
>
> subd2 construction fails:
>          original dictionary doesn't contain some keys
>
> Dictionary constructed using some bad keys:
>          {'b': 1, 'd': 3, 'f': 5, 'h': 7, 'j': 9, 'l': 11, 'n': 13, 'p': 15, 'r': 17, 't': 19, 'v': 21, 'x': 23, 'z': 25}

Comment: Subclassing requires an existing dict object to be converted into the subclass type, which can be expensive. Why not just write a simple function `subdict(orig_dict, keys, …)`?

Comment: @musiphil: I doubt there's much difference in overhead. The nice thing about subclassing is the method is part of the class and doesn't need to be imported or in-lined. Only potential problem or limitation of the code in this answer is the result is *not* of type `my_dict`.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another one (I prefer Mark Longair's answer)

```
di = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
req = ['a','c','w']
dict([i for i in di.iteritems() if i[0] in di and i[0] in req])
```

Comment: its slow for **big**dict's

Answer (score 2):

**solution**

```py
from operator import itemgetter
from typing import List, Dict, Union


def subdict(d: Union[Dict, List], columns: List[str]) -> Union[Dict, List[Dict]]:
    """Return a dict or list of dicts with subset of 
    columns from the d argument.
    """
    getter = itemgetter(*columns)

    if isinstance(d, list):
        result = []
        for subset in map(getter, d):
            record = dict(zip(columns, subset))
            result.append(record)
        return result
    elif isinstance(d, dict):
        return dict(zip(columns, getter(d)))

    raise ValueError('Unsupported type for `d`')
```

**examples of use**

```py
# pure dict

d = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
print(subdict(d, ['a', 'c']))

>>> In [5]: {'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

```py
# list of dicts

d = [
    dict(a=1, b=2, c=3),
    dict(a=2, b=4, c=6),
    dict(a=4, b=8, c=12),
]

print(subdict(d, ['a', 'c']))

>>> In [5]: [{'a': 1, 'c': 3}, {'a': 2, 'c': 6}, {'a': 4, 'c': 12}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way in py3.8+ that avoids `None` values for keys missing from `big_dict` uses the walrus:

```py
small_dict = {key: val for key in ('l', 'm', 'n') if (val := big_dict.get(key))}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using map (halfdanrump's answer) is best for me, though haven't timed it...

But if you go for a dictionary, and if you have a big_dict:

1. Make absolutely certain you loop through the the req. This is crucial, and affects the running time of the algorithm (big O, theta, you name it)
2. Write it generic enough to avoid errors if keys are not there.

so e.g.:

```
big_dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,................................................}
req = ['a','c','w']

{k:big_dict.get(k,None) for k in req )
# or 
{k:big_dict[k] for k in req if k in big_dict)
```

Note that in the converse case, that the req is big, but my_dict is small, you should loop through my_dict instead.

In general, we are doing an intersection and [the complexity of the problem is O(min(len(dict)),min(len(req)))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102478/intersection-complexity/8102505). Python's [own implementation of intersection](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c) considers the size of the two sets, so it seems optimal. Also, being in c and part of the core library, is probably faster than most not optimized python statements.
Therefore, a solution that I would consider is:

```
dict = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,................................................}
req = ['a','c','w',...................]

{k:dic[k] for k in set(req).intersection(dict.keys())}
```

It moves the critical operation inside python's c code and will work for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants first few items `n` of the dictionary without knowing the keys:

```py
n = 5 # First Five Items
ks = [*dikt.keys()][:n]
less_dikt = {i: dikt[i] for i in ks}
```

Comment: This is actually a nice way to 'snip' a section from a big dictionary.