# Intersection complexity

Tags: python, set, complexity-theory

In Python you can get the intersection of two sets doing:

```
>>> s1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
>>> s2 = {0, 3, 5, 6, 10}
>>> s1 & s2
set([3, 5, 6])
>>> s1.intersection(s2)
set([3, 5, 6])
```

Anybody knows the complexity of this intersection (`&`) algorithm?

**EDIT:** In addition, does anyone know what is the data structure behind a Python set?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer appears to be [a search engine query away](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=python+set+intersection+complexity). You can also use this [direct link to the Time Complexity page at python.org](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set). Quick summary:

```
Average:     O(min(len(s), len(t))
Worst case:  O(len(s) * len(t))
```

EDIT: As Raymond points out below, the "worst case" scenario isn't likely to occur. I included it originally to be thorough, and I'm leaving it to provide context for the discussion below, but I think Raymond's right.

Comment: that's a nasty worst case, isn't it?

Comment: I was surprised by it as well! Maybe it's an issue of having different data types mixed in the two sets being intersected?

Comment: It doesn't look like it uses a sort first (which *requires the objects have an ordering*), but rather just does a "hash probe": perhaps for a better `C` and Average (and *no ordering requirement*). The maximum required complexity, AFAIK, is about `O(n log n) + O(n)`, with a sort. However, Big-O is an upper-bounds and there are practical considerations so...

Comment: I think the major issue here is that the set is an unordered collection. In C++, you can make an intersection (with two sorted lists) in 2*(L1+L2)-1. That's a damn good complexity! http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/

Comment: Nice! I really appreciate the insight; hash collisions make bunches of sense. +1's all around!

Comment: This answer is somewhat misleading with respect to the "worst case" time.  Don't let it lead you away from a perfectly fine algorithm.

Comment: I agree with you; fixed. Again, I appreciate the discussion!

Comment: Please don't say "google it" in these answers. These answers often become the results of googling something. This answer was the first search result for me.

Comment: Likelihood of something happening is irrelevant when discussion the "worst case". The worst case is the worst case as long as there is a nonzero chance of it happening. However, if Python is using a hash table, that $n^2$ complexity should not happen ever. Therefore, it's not even the worst case at all.

Comment: @user124384 It's funny how the first search result is this thread from that hyperlink

Answer (score 30):

The data structure behind the set is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) where the typical performance is an amortized `O(1)` lookup and insertion.

The [intersection algorithm](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/setobject.c#l1240) loops exactly `min(len(s1), len(s2))` times. It performs one lookup per loop and if there is a match performs an insertion.  In pure Python, it looks like this:

```
    def intersection(self, other):
        if len(self) <= len(other):
            little, big = self, other
        else:
            little, big = other, self
        result = set()
        for elem in little:
            if elem in big:
                result.add(elem)
        return result
```

Comment: According to the wiki I linked above, the worst case for `elem in big` in your code is O(n) (although the average is of course O(1)). That's the basis for the intersection worst case of O(len(s)*len(t)). Any idea why?

Comment: The "worst case" assumes data that is inappropriate for use in the hash table used by *dict* and *set*.   The data would have to be something such that every datum had exactly the same hash value -- this would force the hash table to do something akin to a linear search to do the \_\_contains\_\_ check.  IOW, I wouldn't worry about this at all.  Set intersection is blindly fast -- it even reuses the internally stored hash values so it won't need to make any calls to *hash()*.

Comment: Link to 3.x code: [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Objects/setobject.c#L1181) it is for 3.9.

Comment: The intersection algorithm does not "always run" in the stated complexity, as acknowledged in the comment by @RaymondHettinger above. In practice it may not matter much, but note that this answer in incorrect in theory.

Comment: @lusil That is profoundly misleading. It is akin to saying that gamblers could consistently win every spin of a roulette wheel. 

It is true that hash tables are a probabilistic algorithm; however,  the odds are very heavily stacked in favor of the user. Given a large table and a randomized hash function, the chances of the intersection algorithm "losing" are infinitesimally low and likely to never occur.

Comment: I like the current wording much better!

Answer (score 2):

Set intersection of two sets of sizes `m,n` can be achieved with `O(max{m,n} * log(min{m,n}))` in the following way:
Assume `m << n`

```
1. Represent the two sets as list/array(something sortable)
2. Sort the **smaller** list/array (cost: m*logm)
3. Do until all elements in the bigger list has been checked:
    3.1 Sort the next **m** items on the bigger list(cost: m*logm)
    3.2 With a single pass compare the smaller list and the m items you just sorted and take the ones that appear in both of them(cost: m)
4. Return the new set
```

The loop in step 3 will run for `n/m` iterations and each iteration will take `O(m*logm)`, so you will have time complexity of `O(nlogm)` for m << n.

I think that's the best lower bound that exists