# How to check for common elements between two lists in python

Tags: python, list

I am having a bit of trouble when I try and check for overlapping elements in list.

This means that I will have to check for common elements between two lists.

The way in which my programme works is that the player enters their two end coordinates for a certain ship, it then creates a list out of this of all of the ships coordinates (ie if they enter `(1,1)` and `(1,5)`, it would create `[(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]`

I have also tried using the following code but it doesn't work for the way I want it to:

```
ListA = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]
ListB = [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)]

    for i in ListB:
        if i in ListA:
            print("There is an overlap")
            #choose coordinates again
        else:
            print("There is no overlap")
            #add to ListA and next ship's coordinate chosen
```

I would like for the program to check to see if any of the elements in A are in B by considering them collectively, instead of checking them individually.

Comment: There is probably around 10 same questions in here. Another 10 on the web. Use uncle google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[set.intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) will find any common elements:

```
ListA = [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5)]
ListB = [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)]
print(set(ListA).intersection(ListB))
set([(1, 1)])
```

Unless order matters it may be just as well to store the tuples in sets:

```
st_a = {(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)}
st_b = {(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)}
print(st.intersection(st_b))
```

add it to your code with:

```
if st_a.intersection(st_b):
     print("There is an overlap")            
else:
    print("There is no overlap")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great, all sorted now

Answer (score 0):

If there is an overlap you want to choose coordinates again;

```
for i in ListB:
    if i in ListA:
        print("There is an overlap")
        i=(yourcoordinateshere)
```

Else you want to add it to `ListA`;

```
else:
    print("There is no overlap")
    ListA.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps...

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: import random

In [3]: lst = [random.randrange(0, 9) for i in xrange(1000)]

In [4]: counted = Counter(lst)

In [7]: counted.most_common(10)
Out[7]: 
[(2, 125),
 (0, 123),
 (5, 120),
 (8, 118),
 (7, 111),
 (1, 107),
 (4, 104),
 (6, 102),
 (3, 90)]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Dictionary

If in practice:

```
 len(ListA) * len(ListB) * ExpectedNumberOfCollisionChecks
```

is significant then it may make sense to use a dictionary for the longer list because the time complexity for a dictionary lookup is:

- Average:     O(1)
- Worst case:  O(n)

Where the average is expected and the worst case happens only when a bad hash function has been selected.

### Intersecting Sets

The accepted answer proposes using `set.intersection`. The [time complexity of `set.intersection`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8102505/2101909) is:

- Average:     O(n)
- Worst case:  O(n^2)

### Modified Code

The only change to your original code is conversion of `ListA` to `MapA`.

```
MapA = {(1,1): True, (1,2): True, (1,3): True,(1,4): True, (1,5): True}
ListB = [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)]

for i in ListB:
    if MapA.get(i):
        print("There is an overlap")
        #choose coordinates again
    else:
        print("There is no overlap")
        #add to ListA and next ship's coordinate chosen
```

### Comments

Going further, the entire intersection operation has to be run each time the user inputs new coordinates (i.e. `ListB` changes). On the other hand the expensive operation most expensive operation: hashing `ListA`, only occurs once. Insertions and deletions from a dictionary have good time complexity:

- Average:     O(1)
- Worst case:  O(n)

For lists, if order does not matter then inserting into a list is always O(1) and regardless of if we care about order deletions are always O(n).