# What is the complexity evaluation of O(m * n) + O((m + n) * log(m + n))

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I have following Python code, a and b are lists(I know it isn't best way of getting intersections):

```
def get_intersection(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    c = sorted(list(a&b))
    return c
```

Let's call len(a) - m and len(b) - n, where is no additional information about a and b. Then time complexity of given code is O(m) + O(n) + O(m * n) + O((m + n) * log(m + n)).

I definitely can shorten O(m) and O(n), because they are much less than O(m * n), but what should I do with O((m + n) * log(m + n))? 
How do i compare O(m * n) and O((m + n) * log(m + n))? Should I keep O((m + n) * log(m + n)) in final evaluation?

Comment: Asymptotically O(mn) is dominant for sure. Someone with fresh calculus is invited to prove it :)

Comment: `m` and `n` are not separate components. You combined input size is just the cumulative size of both arguments.

Comment: `a & b` wouldn't be O(m*n) anyway; it's O(m + n ) as well, because set lookup is O(1).

Comment: `c = sorted(a&b)` would also be sufficient; `sorted` returns a list, but can sort any iterable.

Comment: @chepner according to python wiki worst case of sets intersection is O(m * n): https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: It's a very odd worst-case. Raymond Hettinger discusses this in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8102536/1126841) and a comment on that answer. In short, it only happens if you have data that uses a laughably bad hash function in the first place.

Comment: For example, there is no worst case for sets of integers that would achieve O(n^2) behavior. It's entirely dependent on the type of value *in* the set, not the set itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the total input size as `n`; it doesn't really matter which argument contributes what to that total. (The two extremes are when one or the other argument is empty; moving items from one argument to the other doesn't change the overall amount of work you'll be doing.)

As such, both `set(a)` and `set(b)` are O(n) operations.

`a & b` is also O(n); you don't need to compare every element of `a` to every element of `b` to compute the intersection, because sets are hash-based. You basically just make O(n) constant-time lookups. (I am ignoring the horrific corner case that makes set lookup linear. If you data has a hash function that doesn't map every item to the same value, you won't hit the worst case.)

`sorted(a&b)` (no need to create a list first, but that's also just an O(n) operation) takes O(n lg n).

Because each of the preceding operations is performed in sequence, the total complexity of `get_intersection` is O(n lg n).

Comment: "You can treat the total input size as n": no, this is wrong. m and n are independent numbers, and so are m+n and mn.

Comment: But there's no *reason* to create the two lists separately. Neither `m` nor `n` ever appear apart in the overall complexity, only in combination `m + n`, so it doesn't make any difference whether one is larger than the other. Cf. a graph algorithm that's O(n lg n + m) that scales differently depending on whether it is sparse (m = O(n)) or dense (m = O(n^2).

Comment: I've already dispensed with any need to consider the product `mn`.

Comment: "I've already dispensed with any need to consider the product mn": this is wrong.

Comment: I'm ignoring that, because it's not a realistic concern. Set intersection is only quadratic if you do something stupid and put data that can't be properly hashed in the set.

Comment: This is wrong. Asymptotic complexity is asymptotic complexity. You may not cherry pick the terms you like. And even less disregard the expression given to you.

Comment: I'm taking a more practical stance: this is specifically a Python question, not an algorithm on a theoretical Turing machine. If there is no point in using a `set` to improve performance for a data type that can't take advantage of the `set`, I'm going to ignore it.

Comment: Don't be so bad faith. The question is about asymptotic complexity using the big-O notation, you know it very well. And please don't try to discredit me by random references to the theory of algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can simplify the expression.

Indeed, if you set `m` to a constant value, say `5`, you have a complexity

```
5n + (n+5)log(n+5) = O(n log(n))
```

and the first term is absorbed.

But if you set `m = n`,

```
n² + 2n log(2n) = O(n²)
```

and this time the second term is absorbed. Hence all you can write is

```
O(mn + (m+n) log(m+n)).
```

With a change of variable such that `s` is the sum and `p` the product,

```
O(p + s log(s)).
```

Comment: You answer is right for algorithm with complexity O(m * n) + O((m + n) * log(m + n)), but I incorrectly assumed that the complexity of intersection in python is O(m * n). In fact it is O(m + n), as chepner pointed out in comment section. So for my code final complexity is O(m + n) + O((m + n) * log(m + n)) = O((m + n) * log(m + n))