# extracting dictionary pairs based on value

Tags: python

I want to copy pairs from this dictionary based on their *values* so they can be assigned to new variables. From my research it seems easy to do  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352546/best-way-to-extract-subset-of-key-value-pairs-from-python-dictionary-object) based on keys, but in my case the values are what I'm tracking.

```
things = ({'alpha': 1, 'beta': 2, 'cheese': 3, 'delta': 4})
```

And in made-up language I can assign variables like so -

```
smaller_things =  all values =3 in things
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.items()` to traverse through the pairs and make changes like this:

```
smaller_things = {}
for k, v in things.items():
    if v == 3:
        smaller_things[k] = v
```

If you want a one liner and only need the keys back, list comprehension will do it:

```
smaller_things = [k for k, v in things.items() if v == 3]

>>> things = { 'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
>>> [k for k, v in things.items() if v == 3]
['a', 'c']
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for- Im new to python and recognize everything except that last line- can you explain how that works?

Comment: @wim I'm running 2.7 and both worked the same way, so it seems. Do you forsee any issues with this?

Comment: List comprehension is a way of creating lists from complex expressions. In this example, I'm taking all values of k (the key from `.items()`) when v (the value) matches 3. Check out the list comp documentation, they're awesome - http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: They will both work the same way, but `iteritems` is more efficient and it's just a good habit to get into to use iterators if you don't actually need to build the whole list in memory.

Comment: @wim I like the sound of that- out of curiosity how much faster are we talking about if my list has 30,000 pairs?

Comment: FWIW, should also highlight the syntax in the example for OP:  The neat trick not commented on is the multiple assignment. For k,v creates two variables at the same time from the two items in tuples returned by items or iteritems

Comment: @wim +1 for my first lesson in optimization

Comment: Worth noting that some benefits of the implementation of `.iteritems` was rolled into `.items` as part of the 3k changes to dicts. `.items` is preferred for portable code but if you need performance on Py2.x, definitely consider using `.iteritems`.

Answer (score 0):

kindly this answer is as per my understanding of your question . 
The dictionary is a kind of hash table , the main intension of dictionary is providing the non integer indexing to the values . The keys in dictionary are just like indexes .

for suppose consider the "array" , the elements in array are addressed by the index , and we have index for the elements not the elements for index . Just like that we have keys(non integer indexes) for values in dictionary .

And there is one implication the values in dictionary are non hashable I mean the values in dictionary are mutable and keys in dictionary are immutable ,simply values could  be changed any time .

simply  it is  not good approach to address any thing by using values in dictionary

Comment: valid point, though I am planning for the values to change. Eventually I will be working with realtime data visualization, so the values will be contributing to the animated "flow" of the visualizations. But again you make an important point regarding best practices when working with dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

you can just reverse the dictionary and pull from that:

```
keys_values = { 1:"a", 2:"b"}
values_keys = dict(zip(keys_values.values(), keys_values.keys()))
print values_keys
>>>  {"a":1, "b":2}
```

That way you can do whatever you need to with standard dictionary syntax.

The potential drawback is if you have non-unique values in the original dictionary; items in the original with the same value will have the same key in the reversed dictionary, so you can't guarantee which of the original keys would be the new value. And potentially some values are unhashable (such as lists).

Unless you have a compulsive need to be clever, iterating over items is easier:

```
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    if matches_condition(val):
        do_something(key)
```

Comment: -1 _some_ of the values may be unhashable, making the dict reversal impossible.

Comment: @theodox there should be a point system for exposing potential gotchas:]