# Merge Two Dictionaries that Share Same Key:Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I know this can be done with lists, but I'm just trying to figure out how to do this with dictionaries.

Basically, it'll go like this:

```
dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 12, 'c': 9}
dict2 = {'a': 10, 'b': 3, 'c': 9}

def intersect(dict1, dict2):
    combinDict = dict()


....
print(combinDict)
{'a': 10, 'c':9}
```

So I only want the keys with the same value added into a new dictionary.

Any help?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18554039/489590

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the *intersection* of the items:

```
dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 12, 'c': 9}
dict2 = {'a': 10, 'b': 3, 'c': 9}

print dict(dict1.viewitems() & dict2.items())
{'a': 10, 'c': 9}
```

For python 3 you just want to use items:

```
 dict(dict1.items() & dict2.items())
```

`dict1.items() & dict2.items()` returns a set of key/value pairings that are common to both dicts:

```
In [4]: dict1.viewitems() & dict2.items()
Out[4]: {('a', 10), ('c', 9)}
```

Then we simply call the dict constructor on that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be to use a dict comprehension:

```
In [1]: dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 12, 'c': 9}

In [2]: dict2 = {'a': 10, 'b': 3, 'c': 9}

In [3]: {key: dict1[key] for key in dict1 if dict1[key] == dict2.get(key)}
Out[3]: {'a': 10, 'c': 9}
```

This should be *teeny weeny* bit faster, though that wouldn't matter for regular dictionaries.