# How to matMatching two dictionary key values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a loop, it should trigger on the first if, but it doesn't.

If I print the values

```
print("Books: {0} {1} {2} {3}".format(book['bookid'], allbooks['bookid'], book['Author'], allbooks['Author']))
```

I get:
    Books: 0001 0001 AJHartley AJHartley

I've tried:

```
if book['bookid'] in allbooks['bookid'] and book['Author'] in allbooks['Author']:
    book_exists += 1

if book['bookid'] == allbooks['bookid'] and book['Author'] == allbooks['Author']:
    book_exists += 1
```

The only way I can get a match is if I have

```
if "0001" in book['bookid'] and "AJHartley" in allbooks['Author']:
book_exists += 1
```

But I'd like to compare two dictionary key values.

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Do you want to check dictionnaries intersection? look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554012/intersecting-two-dictionaries-in-python#18554081)

Comment: I have a dictionary of dictionaries. Each sub dictionary contains library book references. So when entering a new book I want to check if it already exists in the library. So if the book id and book author already exist i'll just increase the book_exists count instead of entering in all the details again.

Comment: The exact form of your data structure is unclear, and this is because you did not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Thus there is little way to give concrete advice.