# Check if two dictionaries are disjoint

Tags: python, dictionary, set-intersection, disjoint-sets

Is there an easier/faster way to find out if two dictionaries are disjoint than calculating their intersection?

For the intersection I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554012/intersecting-two-dictionaries-in-python), so the disjoint-test would look like this:

```
def dicts_disjoint(a, b):
    keys_a = set(a.keys())
    keys_b = set(b.keys())
    intersection = keys_a & keys_b
    return not len(intersection)
```

However I think this is inefficient since it always calculates the whole intersection (no short-circuit quit).

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
def dicts_disjoint(a, b):
    return not any(k in b for k in a)
```

Or:

```
def dicts_disjoint(a, b):
    return all(k not in b for k in a)
```

Both will short-circuit.

Comment: it might be easier to read as `all(k not in b for k in a)`. I always have to read the `not any`s twice xD

Comment: Are you sure this is **faster** (as OP wants) than set intersection?

Comment: @randomir Due to short-circuiting and the arbitrary nature of dicts it is very hard to say. This is a problem of statistics. For what it's worth, I believe it is faster.

Comment: This will depend on the size of the dict, it will be faster for smaller dicts. Both are `O(n)` but the set intersection will have the advantage of `C` code for larger dicts to overcome the `set()` construction, providing most are disjoint.

Comment: this is neat, I like it

Comment: And I suppose if you have a very large dict and a very small one it is a lot faster if `a` is the smaller one. Correct? (Assuming dict lookup is constant time)

Comment: Yes, `dict` lookup is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 9):

Don't convert to a set; a `dict_keys` object already supports `isdisjoint`.

```
d1.keys().isdisjoint(d2)
```

Comment: +1, Python 3 only, but I did not know this, it's the only (non-private) method provided by `.keys()` it seems!

Answer (score 4):

**Edited to display methods and timings only**

Since the OP asked about the fastest method to perform this operation, I've ranked the ones under discussion according to a (I hope) fair test on my machine. The aim is to find if the keys of a dictionary are disjoint, and it seems the `dict_keys.isdisjoint()` method wins out over other set or list operations.

However, as mentioned in other answers, this will vary considerably depending on the size of the relative dictionaries and whether or not they are disjoint.

These tests are only for two disjoint dictionaries of equal (small) size.

**Fastest: `dict_keys.isdisjoint()`**

Example:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }.keys().isdisjoint({ "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}.keys())
```

Timing:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }.keys().isdisjoint({ "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}.keys())')
0.4637166199972853
```

**Second Fastest: `set.isdisjoint()`**

Example:

```
set({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }.keys()).isdisjoint(set({ "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}.keys()))
```

Timing:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('set({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }.keys()).isdisjoint(set({ "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}.keys()))')
0.774243315012427
```

**Third Fastest: List Comp and `all()`:**

Example:

```
all(k not in {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 } for k in { "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6})
```

Timing:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('all(k not in {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 } for k in { "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6})')
0.8577601349970791
```

**Fourth Fastest: Symmetric Difference (`^`) with `not()`**

Example:

```
not set({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }.keys()) ^ set({ "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}.keys())
```

Timing:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('not set({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }.keys()) ^ set({ "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}.keys())')
0.9617313010094222
```

Comment: This is - of course, if you're only looking to see if no keys are shared.

Comment: `not bool(x)` is just `not x`. Converting with `set` is a waste of time and won't short-circuit. `^` won't short-circuit.

Comment: Good point @Veedrac - although I sometimes write `bool()` to aid readability, removing it sped up the script considerably. Not sure what you mean about short-circuiting `^` though? This operation only works on sets to my knowledge...

Comment: Your third test is not a valid comparison. You would use dicts instead of lists, and `k not in list` runs in linear time while `k not in dict` takes constant. So its highly dependent on the input size.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited it to reflect a fair timing for all methods.

Answer (score 1):

Using only bit operation:
variables

```
dict1 = {"a":1, "b":2}
dict2 = {"a":4, "c":2}
```

union

```
dict1.keys() | dict2.keys()
# {'b', 'a', 'c'}
```

intersection

```
dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()
# {'a'}
```

disjoint

```
dict1.keys() ^ dict2.keys()
# {'b', 'c'}
```

Then set a condition:

```
"different" if dict1.keys() ^ dict2.keys() else "equal"
```

*An empty set() return "False" in boolean conditions*