# How to intersect dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, set-intersection

I haven't taken python in a long time and am a bit rusty but for the first question I'm taking a dictionary and need to intersect it returning the key and the value. So for example, I'm entering

```
a = {1:'a1', 2.5:'a2', 4:'a3'}
b = {1:'a1', 3:'a2',  5:'a4'}
```

If I enter `c = intersect(a,b)`, I want it to return `{1:'a1'}`, but I only get back `{'a1'}`.

My code so far is:

```
def intersect(a, b):
    for i in a:
        if j in b:
            if a[i]==b[i]:
                return ({i})
        else:
            return {}
```

Comment: Sorry I meant {1:'a1'} (laptop is autocorrecting) which is in both a and b.

Comment: So `{k: v for (k, v) in a.items() if k in b}`?

Comment: What if values don't match?

Comment: Your `intersect` code tests `j` but never assigns it anything.

Comment: The way in which you're iterating over each of the dictionaries *only iterates over the keys*, not the values. To access the values, use either `dict.items()` or `dict.values()`.

Answer (score 6):

You could simplify this, using *actual* `set` intersection. This retains only shared items (key and value the same):

```
def intersect(a, b):
    return dict(a.items() & b.items())
```

If your `dict` params have non-hashable values, you can go for a `dict` comprehension along the following lines:

```
def intersect(a, b):
    return {k: a[k] for k in a if b.get(k, not a[k]) == a[k]}
```

And you can fix your original approach like so:

```
def intersect(a, b):
    d = {}
    for i in a:
        if i in b and a[i] == b[i]:
            d[i] = a[i]
    return d
```

Comment: Could you tell me why you used items and dict? In my first code I wrote the same things except I didn't have those two included.

Comment: @coco_11 `set(a)` is equivalent to `set(x for x in a)` and if `a` is a `dict`, this will only produce its keys. Hence the `items` call. And since items are a list of pairs, you have to call `dict` on it again.

Comment: In Python 3, items aren't given as a list. Try `dict(a.items() & b.items())`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann True, but the solution given in my answer works in both Py 2 and 3. And the question is not tagged with a specific version.

Comment: Yeah I just meant your comment "items are a list of pairs"

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yeah, the point there was on the pairs. Whatever the type of iterable, if it produces pairs, you can pass it to the `dict` constructor.

Comment: FWIW, I think the `if b.get(k, not a[k]) == a[k]` is ingenious.

Comment: **From 2021:** Python 2 is thankfully long dead, so `dict(a.items() & b.items())` is the correct approach. Coercing *two* `ItemsView` containers into sets needlessly consumes space and time.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a version of the `intersect` function, that intersects the keys and uses the values of the first dictionary, that means in case of different values, this function is biased towards the value in the first dictionary:

```
def intersect(a, b):
    return {k: a[k] for k in a.keys() & b.keys()}
```

This works because, the `dict_keys` view objects returned by `dict.keys()` (since Python 3) are sets (i.e. implement `collections.abc.Set`).

If you want to customize, which value will be used, we can use a function, that takes both values:

```
def intersect(a, b, select=lambda a, b: a):
    return {k: select(a[k], b[k]) for k in a.keys() & b.keys()}
```

Instead of returning one of the values, we could then also e.g. add the values:

```
>>> intersect({'a': 4, 'b': 3}, {'a': 5}, lambda a, b: a + b)
{'a': 9}
```

Comment: But this does not enforce `k` to have the same value in `a` and `b`

Comment: Nothing in the OPs question stated, that this is desired. I also provided a way to customize the behaviour.