# Compare dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
dict1 = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3
}

dict2 = {
    key1: value1,
    key4: value4,
    key3: value2
}
fdict = {}
```

when I compare the above two dictionaries, I want to store key1: value1 to fdict dictionary:

my attempt:

```
for key in dict1.keys():
    if key in dict2.keys():
        if dict1[key] == dict2[key]:
            fdict[key] == dict1[key]
```

I am having "key error" when I tried above method..
any suggestions?

Comment: where are `content` and `new_dict` defined?

Comment: well, as it sits, none of your keys exist because you didnt provide variables or you didn't surround with quotes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code has syntax and semantic errors that prevent it from reaching the error state you posted.

Comment: Besides the [great answer below](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) You can also check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49710152/2996101).

Comment: Are you sure that `fdict` contains `key` that you try to compare?
P.S. Replace `==` to `=` in last line, if I correctly understand you needs.

Answer (score 7):

Well, for one, you get `KeyError` because you try to look up keys which don't exist in both dicionaries.

It sounds to me like you want to compute an intersection of two dictionaries. In such case, it's enough to:

```
>>> a = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
>>> b = dict(b=2, c=3, d=4)
>>> dict(a.items() & b.items())
{'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: wait, does that work?

Comment: Sure, just type it into the interpreter.

Comment: This is some nice Python!

Comment: I honestly didn't know that dict views had set-like intersection/union operators

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty cool. It works for union (`|`) and difference (`^`) too.

Comment: difference `-` and symmetric difference `^`... wow, i honeslty didn't think I had anything left to learn about dictionaries https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/#specification and https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Comment: @FHTMitchell Indeed this is great, thanks to OP who is severely downvoted, however.

Comment: @Siegmeyer it does not work when we have lists as values in dictionary

Comment: @YetAnotherComputerGuy Yes, lists are unhashable. If your problem relates to lists, please state so in the description.