# Check if any key exist from given multiple keys in a given dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, subset, python-3.6

I know the best way to check if the multiple keys exist in a given dictionary.

```
if {'foo', 'bar'} <= my_dict.keys():
    # True
```

Now I have to check if there is any key exist in given dictionary and got so far this:

```
if any(k in given_keys for k in my_dict):
    # True
```

I was wondering if there is any way to check this as checked above in first case using subset.

Comment: More https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554012/intersecting-two-dictionaries-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similarly:

```
if {'foo', 'bar'} & my_dict.keys():
    print(True)
```

`&` means intersection.

Comment: It can get even more concise with `print(set() != given_keys & my_dict.keys())`

Comment: @MicheleBastione no need to do it. Empty set evaluates to `False` in boolean context. Doing `if some_set:` to check if `some_set` is empty is the most pythonic way.

Comment: Swings and roundabouts I guess. Simply printing the result will try to print the set contents, not true/false. I guess you could bool cast it.. Anyway, in reality I guess you want to do something more interesting with the result than print true/false, so this answer is good for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

Using list compreenssion you can compare two dictionaries:

```
[x for x in my_dict2 if x in my_dict]
```

The generator of a dict always use the keys to compare both you will need to use dict.items()