# How can I get multiple shared items between two dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, intersection

```py
length_word = {'pen':3, 'bird':4, 'computer':8, 'mail':4} 
count_word = {'pen':10, 'bird':50, 'computer':3, 'but':45, 'blackboard': 12, 'mail':12}

intersection = length_word.items() - count_word.items() 
common_words = {intersection}
```

Err: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`

I wish to get this dictionary:

```
outcome = {'pen':10, 'bird':50, 'computer':3, 'mail':12}
```

Thanks.

Comment: A set as an unhashable type can not be part of an other set nor a key in a dictionary.

Comment: See this post, it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554012/intersecting-two-dictionaries-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.keys()` instead of `.items()`.
Here is a solution:

```
length_word = {'pen':3, 'bird':4, 'computer':8, 'mail':4}
count_word = {'pen':10, 'bird':50, 'computer':3, 'but':45, 'blackboard': 12, 'mail':12}
intersection = count_word.keys() & length_word.keys()    

common_words = {i : count_word[i] for i in intersection}

#Output: 
{'computer': 3, 'pen': 10, 'mail': 12, 'bird': 50}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intersection = count_word.keys() & length_word.keys()    

outcome = dict((k, count_word[k]) for k in intersection)
```

Answer (score 0):

try getting the intersection (common keys). one you have the common keys access those keys from the `count_words`.

```
res = {x: count_word.get(x, 0) for x in set(count_word).intersection(length_word)}
```

**res:**

```
{'bird': 50, 'pen': 10, 'computer': 3, 'mail': 12}
```

Comment: Why use `get` with a default rather than `count_word[x]`?

Comment: @superbrain: Yes actually If you are going for union thing then use `get`. For this case it's not required to use get so yeah one can use directly also.

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop check if the key is present in both the dictionary. If so then add that key, value pair to new dictionary.

```
length_word = {'pen':3, 'bird':4, 'computer':8, 'mail':4}
count_word = {'pen':10, 'bird':50, 'computer':3, 'but':45, 'blackboard': 12, 'mail':12}
my_dict = {}

for k, v in count_word.items():
    if k in length_word.keys():
        my_dict[k] = v

print(my_dict)
```

Comment: Why not simply `if k in length_word:`?

Comment: Yes we can do that.  Can you please explain  what is the difference between two?

Comment: Hmm, I'd say the difference is that one way does useless extra work and the other doesn't :-). I can't tell why you did that extra work, only you know.

Comment: I mean, `.keys()` every time creates an keys view object for no benefit, and the whole second half of your condition checks whether the key is in the dict that you just got it from.

Comment: Yes you are right. I corrected my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just another dict comp:

```
outcome = {k: v for k, v in count_word.items() if k in length_word}
```