# How to use map() of threadPoolExecutor in case of nested for loop in python

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I have 2 Dictionaries,

```py
data1 = {
  "key": [
    {
      "id": "key1",
      "name": "key1"
    },
    {
      "id": "key2",
      "name": "key2"
    },
    {
      "id": "key3",
      "name": "key3"
    },
  ]
}

data2 = {
  "key": [
    {
      "id": "key2"
      "name": "TEST key2"
    },
    {
      "id": "key1",
      "name": "TEST key1"
    },
  ]
}
```

I am making a list of tuples of the objects inside the `key` list in `data1` and `data2` having matching `id`, using the below code

```py
common_keys = [
    (each_data1_key, each_data2_key)
    for each_data1_key in data1.get("key", [])
    for each_data2_key in data2.get("key", [])
    if each_data1_key.get("id") == each_data2_key.get("id")
]

# Example result = [({"id":"key1", "name": "key1"}, {"id": "key1", "name": "TEST key1"}), ...]
```

Now I want to use these tuples for processing further in threadPoolExecutor's map function. Currently, I am using below code,

```py
def func(object1, object2):
   """
   func is being run in the thread to do some task parallelly with object1 and object2
   """
   <SOME CODE HERE> ...

def myfunc(common_keys):
    if common_keys:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            executor.map(lambda x: func(*x), common_keys)

# func is a function that accepts 2 objects as parameters
# since we are sending tuple of the object in threads, in order to process some task
```

My task is to optimize the code by reducing the loop(I have used nested for loop to find `common_keys` list`

Could anyone help me to find any solution in which, in order to get a list of tuples of the objects having the same id, I don't need to use a nested loop(or, with another optimized way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18554039/9981846, if you have some memory to spare, you can make your ids dictionary keys, to benefit from the fast set-like operations later.

```py
# Loop once for each list
dict1 = {item["id"]: item for item in data1.get("key", [])}
dict2 = {item["id"]: item for item in data2.get("key", [])}

# Set intersection is fast
common_keys = [(dict1[key], dict2[key])
               for key
               in dict1.keys() & dict2.keys()]
```

Also, if you pass the dictionaries to `myfunc`, instead of `common_keys` you can spare the creation of that list using a generator.

```py
def func(object1, object2):
    print(f"Got 1: {object1}, and 2: {object2}")


def generate_pairs(d1, d2):
    for key in d1.keys() & d2.keys():
        yield d1[key], d2[key]


def myfunc(d1, d2):
    if common_keys:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            executor.map(lambda x: func(*x), generate_pairs(d1, d2))


myfunc(dict1, dict2)
>>> Got object1: {'id': 'key2', 'name': 'key2'}, object2: {'id': 'key2', 'name': 'TEST key2'}
>>> Got object1: {'id': 'key1', 'name': 'key1'}, object2: {'id': 'key1', 'name': 'TEST key1'}
```

Finally, to keep speed and spare memory vs above, you could create only the smallest one of the two dictionaries, passing the `"key"` lists to the generator:

```py
def generate_pairs(l1, l2):
    little, big = (l1, l2) if (len(l1) < len(l2)) else (l2, l1)
    d1 = {item["id"]: item for item in little}

    # loop once over the second list
    for key_data_2 in big:
        key_data_1 = d1.get(key_data_2["id"], None)  # Average case fast too
        if key_data_1 is not None:
            yield key_data_1, key_data_2


# with the same `myfunc` except for parameters types
def myfunc(l1, l2):
    if common_keys:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            executor.map(lambda x: func(*x), generate_pairs(l1, l2))


# and you'd call 
myfunc(data1.get("key", []), data2.get("key", []))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is a very nice solution.