# How to cross check dictionaries efficiently

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am new to coding and I am looking to code a function (max_dict) that takes two dictionaries and creates a third dictionary that includes only keys and values where the key was contained in both dictionaries. The code below works, but I want a more efficient way to do it! Thanks!

```
def max_dict(dict1, dict2):
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        for k, v in dict2.items():
            if key == k:
                new_dict[key] = value
    return new_dict
```

Comment: _third dictionary that includes only keys and **values**_, yet you take only value from dict1, what should happen with value from dict2?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554012/intersecting-two-dictionaries and similar.

Comment: @buran has a point; are you trying to save a value from dict1 or dict2 OR: do you mean you ONLY want keys that match BOTH the key AND the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
new_dict = {x:dict1[x] for x in dict1 if x in dict2}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def max_dict(dict1, dict2):
    new_dict = {}
    for key in dict1:
        if (key in dict2 and dict1[key] == dict2[key]):
            new_dict[key]=dict1[key]
    return new_dict
```