# Instantiate attrs class from dict with superfluous key/value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, httpresponse, python-attrs

I decorated a class using `attrs.define` and added all important attributes/fields.

```py
import attrs

@attrs.define
class MyAttrsClass:
    important1 = attrs.field(type = int)
    important2 = attrs.field(type = str)
    [...]
```

Now I would like to initialize instances of that class from a dict.
So what I do is calling the contructor with a dict-unpacking.

```
test_dict = {'important1': 100, 'important2': 'foo'}
ci = MyAttrsClass(**test_dict)
```

This works in that simple example case, because I specify the same fields in the dict as well as in the `MyAttrsClass` class.

However, in the real scenario the dict is a deserialized response from a web-api (using `json.loads`) and it returns many key-value-pairs I'm not interested in, despite the important ones.
Then, I get the following error `TypeError: MyAttrsClass.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'XYZ'`.

Is is possible to initialize an instance of `MyAttrsClass`, though?
I would like to discard the superfluous elements.
Do I need to manually remove entries from the input dict or is there a better way using attrs.

Comment: I told that I wanted to discard the superfluous elements of the input dict. However, if it is easier to keep them, this would not be a problem.

Comment: It's *syntactically* convenient to want to do that, but it assumes that it is the job of a class to somehow pick out the keyword arguments it *wants* from an arbitrary and overly broad set of arguments. Be explicit. If you want something similar, define a class method like `def from_dict(cls, d): return cls(d['important1'], d['important2'])`.

Comment: (Posting as a comment because I don't know if `attrs` does, in fact, provide a way to do this. But it's not something I *expect* it to provide.)

Comment: You can filter them out with something like `[a.name for a in MyAttrsClass.__attrs_attrs__]`.

Comment: I like the class method approach but in order to avoid repetition I would like to pick out the important entries more generically. Maybe it's possible to add some reflection on `MyAttrsClass`?

Comment: Just found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554012/intersecting-two-dictionaries. Maybe this could help in extracting only the important items from the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the documented `attrs.fields` function:

```
big_dic = {"important1": 3, "important2": "abc", "spuriouskey": "dontcare"}
fields = {a.name for a in attrs.fields(MyAttrsClass)}
init_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in big_dic.items() if k in fields}

MyAttrsClass(**init_kwargs)
# MyAttrsClass(important1=3, important2='abc')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an attrs maintainer and the author of [cattrs](https://catt.rs). You should probably just use cattrs since it was designed for cases like this.

```
from cattrs import structure

structure(big_dict, MyAttrsClass)
```

Otherwise, you'll have to do a little preprocessing yourself, as others have mentioned.

Comment: That worked like a charm out of the box. I don't need to reinvent the wheel, now!

Comment: ... and I also put it into a `from_web_response` classmethod of MyAttrsClass as suggested by @chepner.