# Pythonic way to extract specific values from a dictionary based on a subset of keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a set of row dictionaries each has the same keys.  I want to create a pointer using a subset of the keys,

```
mydict = {'g':'1','a':'2','r':'3','c':'24','b':'38'}
```

The pointer might use the values of 'a','g' and 'c'

```
pointer = '-'.join([mydict['a'],mydict['g'],mydict['c']])
```

So the pointer looks like:

```
2-1-24
```

Is there a more general approach to accomplish the pulling of values from a dictionary in a particular order

As I am writing this I wonder if it should be on code review as I can clearly accomplish my objective but this code is not very reusable I would like to do something more 'Pythonic'

I did find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352546/best-way-to-extract-subset-of-key-value-pairs-from-python-dictionary-object) but I don't think it is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Please, use a space after commas. Follow PEP8 if you want "pythonic" code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for a general approach, you might look to the functional tools, for instance `map`.

```
mydict = {'g':'1','a':'2','r':'3','c':'24','b':'38'}
keys = ['a', 'g', 'c']
results = map(mydict.__getitem__, keys)
pointer = '-'.join(results)
```

(obviously the results part can be inlined into the join, but this felt clearer)

In Python, the 'indexing operator' `[]` works by calling the collection's `__getitem__` method (yes, this does mean that if you define a class with a method called `__getitem__` you can use the square brackets to index into it). The `map` function takes a function argument and a collection, and returns a list equivalent to [f(x) for x in coll]

in fact, the above code is equivalent in function to `results = [mydict[x] for x in keys]`, but last I looked `map` was faster.

```
>>> def t1():  
...  mydict = {'g':'1','a':'2','r':'3','c':'24','b':'38'}  
...  keys = ['a', 'g', 'c']  
...  results = map(mydict.`__getitem__`, keys)  
...  
>>> def t2():  
...  mydict = {'g':'1','a':'2','r':'3','c':'24','b':'38'}  
...  keys = ['a', 'g', 'c']  
...  results = [mydict[x] for x in keys]  
...  
`>>>` timeit.timeit(t1, number = 100000)  
0.061136093994718976  
`>>>` timeit.timeit(t1, number = 100000)  
0.05009100399911404  
`>>>` timeit.timeit(t2, number = 100000)  
0.06633162200159859  
`>>>` timeit.timeit(t2, number = 100000)  
0.06771555900922976
```

Comment: Thanks a whole lot this was very helpful.  I really appreciate the extra time you took here.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...

```
pointer = '{data[a]}-{data[g]}-{data[c]}'.format(data=mydict)
```

Looks a bit better, at least.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I marked it up but it is more or less the same as mine, so I did not accept it though I appreciated the effort.