# Reusing dictionary without reconstruction

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, dictionary, data-structures

P/S: The approach in
[best way to extract subset of key-value pairs from python dictionary object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352546/best-way-to-extract-subset-of-key-value-pairs-from-python-dictionary-object)
is recreating a new subkeys' dictionary. It is slow (I have tried it). The answer of using Subdicview given by shx2 below is great in terms of efficiency.

I have a python dictionary, e.g.,

```
d={"a1":Obj1, "a2":Obj2,"a3":Obj3,...,"a10":Obj10}
```

Where `Obj1` to `Objn` is some objects of self created python class.

The problem is that, in a loop of 100 millions time, I need different subset of keys at each iteration, say I need `"a1"` to `"a3"`, what I do now is I reconstructed the dictionary

```
d1={"a1":Obj1, "a2":Obj2,"a3":Obj3}
```

whenever I want to use it. In the end, I do 100 millions reconstructions of dictionaries.

Is there a more efficient way to handle such case (e.g, muting the keys in `d` that I am not interested) without reconstructing the dictionary each time in the loop?

Comment: `in a loop of 100 millions time, I need different subset of keys at each iteration` - Can you please explain?

Comment: Do you have a data structure holding all the subsets for each iteration to start with?

Comment: @shx2 no, which subset is depends on the input data, can assume the subsets are unknown in advanced.

Comment: @william007 Do you have a problem accessing the items with keys?

Comment: @thefourtheye no problems, but say subset is `"a1"`,`"a2"`,`"a3"`, using `d` without reconstructing a new dictionary,  `"a10" in d` will return true, which is not what I want.

Comment: I still don't really understand your question.  How do you intend to "get" the keys you want without creating some kind of new data structure to hold them?

Comment: @BrenBarn I am thinking in the direction that by using the dictionary `d`, I can somehow "mute" the keys I am not interested, but I am opened to any possibilities.

Comment: @william007: Can you give an example of what you actually need to do with the result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [best way to extract subset of key-value pairs from python dictionary object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352546/best-way-to-extract-subset-of-key-value-pairs-from-python-dictionary-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following "lightweight" sub-dict-view class. This is possibly the fastest approach, as it avoids creating new dicts at each iteration (creating the view object is fast).

```
from UserDict import DictMixin

class SubDictView(DictMixin):

    def __init__(self, dct, keys):
        self._dct = dct
        self._keys = keys

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self._keys:
            raise KeyError(key)
        return self._dct[key]

    def keys(self):
        return set(self._dct) & self._keys

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        raise RuntimeError('SubDictView is read-only')

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        raise RuntimeError('SubDictView is read-only')

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dv = SubDictView(d, {'b', 'c'})
print dv
# {'c': 3, 'b': 2}
print 'a' in dv
# False
print dv['b']
# 2
print dv.get('a', 999)
# 999
```

If you already have the subset of keys stored as a `set`, you can gain further speed by avoiding the conversion-to-`set` in `__init__`.

Comment: Thanks, this is in line of what I am thinking of

Comment: @shx2/@william007, So, what you have achieved here is, instead of doing 100 millions reconstructions of dictionaries, you are now doing 100 millions constructions of sets. That won't improve the performance.

Comment: @DebanshuKundu if the keys-subsets are already stored as sets, or set-like (i.e. fast lookup), the conversion-to-set can be skipped, which would make it very fast. Also, if the keys-subsets are guaranteed to be contained in the full set of keys, the implementation of `keys()` can be changed to `return self._keys`, which would speed things up further.

Comment: @shx2, Yes, but then you can also create sub-dictionaries of the original dictionary and use them instead or using the original dictionary. Either way one would have to create 100 millions hashes either inside the loop or before the loop starts.

Comment: @DebanshuKundu under these conditions, creating N views (and accessing them) is much faster than creating N dicts (and accessing them).

Comment: @shx2 Thanks, I have tested this method 
this method is indeed faster than dictionary recreation. I change your answer from list to set, as it would be way more faster without conversion. Even I pass in a set, with set(keys) in SubDicView, it runs slower.

Comment: @DebanshuKundu it indeed runs faster! Even with list conversion it also runs faster, but definitely without conversion is much more faster.

Answer (score 0):

One (speed-oriented) solution would be to use a [`pandas.Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series).

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(d.values(), index = d.keys())
subseries1 = series[:3]
subseries2 = series[10:20]
...
```

If you need a subset of keys which are not consecutive indices, you can still use something like:

```
subseries3 = series.ix[[1,3,8]]
```

though in this case it might prove a bit slower, because this kind of indexing (as opposed to slicing) causes a new series to be created (instead of a view to the original series, which is much faster).

`pandas.Series` has an interface which resembles `dict`s in some ways, so you wouldn't need to changes the rest of your code by much (or at all).

Comment: What if the subset is (1, 3, 8)?

Comment: In that case, I suppose, it is similar to creating a new `dict`?

Comment: @thefourtheye, in that case, yes (but easiesr to code), but if the indices are consecutive, it isn't.

Comment: @shx2 is it possible to use string keys? as in my case the string keys could be like "3dsfd"

Comment: @shx2 but how should I know the subset of keys is say (1,3,8)? since the string can be any like "342dfsaf"

Comment: @william007, index using `['342dfsaf', ...]`. refer to the pandas docs.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is far from clear, but if I understand correctly, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).  If your dictionary is like this:

```
d = {'a1': 1, 'a2': 2, 'a3': 3, 'a4': 4, 'a5': 5}
```

Then:

```
>>> operator.itemgetter('a1', 'a3', 'a5')(d)
(1, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Thanks, but not the question I am asking, so sorry for that. What I need is a dictionary `d` where `"a1" in d` return true, and `"a2" in d` return false, `d["a1"]` will return 1, `d["a2"]` will throw exception, if the subset is `"a1","a3","a5"`

Comment: @william007: Again, can you please explain *where you are getting those keys*.  What is the data structure that holds the values `"a1", "a2", "a3"` that you want to use to make your new dict?

Comment: You can assume they are given by the users, you can assume of any data structures that are holding them.

Answer (score 0):

It is crucial to note that `set(dict)` does *not* create a view in Python 2.7 (as the accepted answer implies).  It creates a set, and doing it that way is actually pretty slow.  Dictionary views in Python 2.7 are accessed by the `view*` methods on dictionaries (in this case, we want `dict.viewkeys()`)