# Extracting value from dictionary based on matching term from a list

Tags: python

Using Python 2.7, I am trying to extract a value from a dictionary, where the key is from a list / set of possible values (and assuming that if any key is present in the dictionary, only one of the possible keys is present). For example, I want to grab the "name" value from a dictionary, where the key could be `name`, `display_name`, `displayName`, or `displayname`. I could do a bunch of `if-elif` statements, but hoping for something more elegant. From these [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352546/best-way-to-extract-subset-of-key-value-pairs-from-python-dictionary-object), I believe I could also do something like:

```
keys = ['name', 'display_name', 'displayName', 'displayname']
data = {'name': 'Foo',
    'baz': 'bim'}

if any(_key in data for _key in keys):
    filtered = {k:v for k, v in data.iteritems() if k in keys}
    display_name = filtered[filtered.keys()[0]]
```

While that is definitely better than `if-elif` statements, is there a one-liner way to do this? (fill in the ????):

```
keys = ['name', 'display_name', 'displayName', 'displayname']
data = {'name': 'Foo',
    'baz': 'bim'}

if any(_key in data for _key in keys):
    display_name = ????
```

I have a bunch of these pairings to find, so that's why I'm looking for simpler solutions.

Comment: What if both `name`and `display_name` are present in the dictionary?

Comment: I'm going to assume only one is present (or, alternatively you just arbitrarily pick one).

Comment: Aha, then the approach of Adam might be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you know only one key will match:

```
In [89]: keys = ['name', 'display_name', 'displayName', 'displayname']
         data = {'name': 'Foo', 'baz': 'bim'}
         data[set(keys).intersection(data.keys()).pop()]
Out[89]: 'Foo'
```

Edit: To explain. `pop()` for a set returns an arbitrary element, so if you know the intersection of the two sets can only be one element, it will always return what you're looking for.