# Performing calculations on some values in a dictionary based on their keys (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Looking to gain some understanding on handling dictionaries efficiently in Python.

I have a dictionary

```
dict = {'a': 11, 'b': 4, 'c': 7, 'd': 12, 'e': 5}
```

and I would like to **perform calculations only on a subset of its values**. Which values to be considered in the calculations is **based on their keys**. Say, that these keys will be in a list of keys.

For example, if I would like to add the values of the keys `a`, `b` and `e` (i.e. `keys_list_to_add`=['a', 'b', 'e']) I would expect the result to be `20`. Note, that several such subsets calculations may exist and a key may be missing (so, perhaps an exception should be raised in that case).

After seeing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5352630/6167676), I tried to implement it with no success cause I am still learning Python. Could you please provide with code suggestions for my problem?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the "subset" of key is actually a subset? Would it be permissible for the answer to raise an exception if a key in the "subset" is not actually in your dictionary?

Comment: @RoryDaulton An exception should be raised if a key is missing, yes. (modified question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the given example with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum) and [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) that returns `dict` values based on keys:

```
>>> d = {'a': 11, 'b': 4, 'c': 7, 'd': 12, 'e': 5}
>>> keys_list_to_add = ['a', 'b', 'e']
>>> sum(d[k] for k in keys_list_to_add)
20
```

It raises `KeyError` in case that given key doesn't exists in the `dict`:

```
>>> keys_list_to_add = ['a', 'b', 'f']
>>> sum(d[k] for k in keys_list_to_add)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
KeyError: 'f'
```

If you want to handle the error in one way or another you could use `try/except`:

```
>>> try:
...     sum(d[k] for k in keys_list_to_add)
... except KeyError:
...     print 'Missing key'
...
Missing key
```

Or you could interpret missing key as `0`:

```
>>> sum(d.get(k, 0) for k in keys_list_to_add)
15
```

Note that you shouldn't use build-in method names like `dict` for variables since that hides the method:

```
>>> dict(a=1)
{'a': 1}
>>> dict = {1:2}
>>> dict(a=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: That is what I want, thanks. Could you please elaborate on how to handle the `keyerror`? I do not understand how at `try..except` or an `if k in keys_list_to_add` befor the `for` loop should be implemented.

Comment: @nk-fford I added couple options on how to handle the missing keys but since I don't know the context it's impossible to tell what's the "correct" way,