# How to merge pairs of dictionaries while dropping a subset of each dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.5

#### Problem Statement:

I'm using python 3.5 and love the new dictionary merging syntax:

```
 merged = {**A, **B}
```

But what if you only wanted some subset of the keys in `A` and `B`?

```
 A_keys = [some small subset of the keys from A]
 B_keys = [some small subset of the keys from B]

 merged = ???
```

Comment: There is no shorthand for that.

Comment: @Prune , there is no problem with question

Comment: I'd go for two simple loops: `merged = {}` `for k in A_keys: merged[k] = A[k]`, same for `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary comprehensions to the rescue:

```
A = { 'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3' }
B = { 'four': '4', 'five': '5', 'six': '6' }
A_keys = ['one', 'two']
B_keys = ['five']
merged = {**{k:v for k,v in A.items() if k in A_keys}, **{k:v for k,v in B.items() if k in B_keys}}
```

Comment: This definitely solves the problem, but isn't too elegant (effectively three dict comprehensions I think). I'll wait to see if some python master has something up their sleeve, otherwise I'll accept this one.

Comment: Well, you can do it with just two comprehensions, but you won't be using the shiny new merge syntax and it won't be as expressive: `merged = {k:v for k,v in A.items() if k in A_keys}; merged.update({k:v for k,v in B.items() if k in B_keys})`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the new notation with [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352546/best-way-to-extract-subset-of-key-value-pairs-from-python-dictionary-object/5352649) to the question about how to select some keys from a dict:

```
merged = { **{ k:A[k] for k in A.keys() & A_keys }, **{ k:B[k] for k in B.keys() & B_keys }}
```

This works even if some values in A_keys or B_keys are not really keys in A or B.

Answer (score -1):

You can access by calling specific keys which you want to merge from both the sets.

```
  dict1 = {'bookA': 1, 'bookB': 2, 'bookC': 3}
  dict2 = {'bookC': 2, 'bookD': 4, 'bookE': 5}
```

Merge the desired keys

```
print (dict1['bookA'] + dict2['bookB'])
```

Result:

```
{'bookE': 5, 'bookD': 4, 'bookB': 2, 'bookA': 1, 'bookC': 3}
```

or you can store the result to new dictonary.

```
y = dict1['bookA'] + dict2['bookB']

print (y)
```

Comment: Who gave negative feedback to my answer and what's wrong with it ?

Comment: Pretty much everything, I'm afraid. `dict1['bookA'] + dict2['bookB']` throws an exception. Even if it worked, the result would not be a dictionary.