# List of dictionaries, comparing 3 of 4 dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare, key

I have a working solution but I was wondering if there is a more elegant or more 'pythonic' solution.
I have a list of dictionaries. Every dictionary has 4 keys.
I need to check if the values of 3 keys of one dictionary are identical to the key values of the next dictionary. 
The code below, marked with '#This code' is the code in question.
Is there a more elegant or more compact way to do this?

I am fairly new to Python, and this is my first post here.
Thank you.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

lst = [{ "fname" : "John", "lname" : "Doe", "age" : 20, "amount":200 },
{ "fname" : "Sue" , "lname" : "Jones", "age" : 17, "amount":800 },
{ "fname" : "Rick", "lname" : "West" , "age" : 25, "amount":280 },
{ "fname" : "Sue" , "lname" : "Jones", "age" : 17, "amount":120 },
{ "fname" : "John", "lname" : "Doe"  , "age" : 20, "amount":100 }]

#Sort list
lst_sorted = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter('fname', 'lname', 'age'))
pprint(lst_sorted)
for i in range(0, len(lst_sorted)-1):
    print(lst_sorted[i])
    print(lst_sorted[i+1])
        #This code
    if ( lst_sorted[i]['fname'] == lst_sorted[i+1]['fname'] ) and \
       ( lst_sorted[i]['lname'] == lst_sorted[i+1]['lname'] ) and \
       ( lst_sorted[i]['age']   == lst_sorted[i+1]['age'] ):
        #/This code/
        print('equal')
    else:
        print('not equal')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352546/extract-subset-of-key-value-pairs-from-python-dictionary-object

Answer (score 1):

First, if you are just comparing sequential items from your sorted list, you could just use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) on two slices:

```py
for a, b in zip(lst_sorted[:-1], lst_sorted[1:]):
    # do things
```

The `zip` operator will produce tuples of the corresponding elements in any number of iterables.

The [:-1] slice will grab everything except the last element, and the [1:] slice will grab everything except the first, effectively offsetting them by one. You can read about slices [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/7867968).

Then, for the comparison, you could use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#all) operator to short-circuit the check on the keys which won't do the entire comparison if one fails. `all(condition_1, ..., condition_n)` is equivalent to `condition_1 and ... and condition_n`:

```py
for a, b in zip(lst_sorted[:-1], lst_sorted[1:]):
    print(a, b)
        #This code
    if all(a.get(k) == b.get(k) for k in ['fname', 'lname', 'age']):
        #/This code/
        print('equal')
    else:
        print('not equal')
```

Where `dict.get` will prevent you from having a `KeyError` in case one is missing

Comment: That is a nice solution.
Thank you so much!