# python 310 build dynamic url query dict from json response

Tags: python, urllib, dictionary-comprehension

How can I return a subset of the `data` dictionary with dict comprehension?

for example

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode, urlparse

data = [{"id": 123, "description": "big one", "productId": 1}, {"id":124, "description": "medium one", "productId": 2}, {"id": 125, "description": "small one", "productId": 3}]

url = urlparse("https://example.api.com/")
for elem in data:
    query = urlencode(
        query={"description": elem.get("description"), "productId": elem.get("productId")}
    )
    path = f"v1/product/{elem['id']}"
    newurl = url._replace(path=path, query=query)
    logger.debug(newurl.geturl())
```

Answer (score 0):

My question is poorly worded. I was hoping to get a subset of a dictionary using keys. Answer is here: [Extract subset of key-value pairs from dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352546/extract-subset-of-key-value-pairs-from-dictionary)